# MongoDB not returning the Data

Tags: database, mongodb, studio3t

I created a database using MongoDB named mydb.
Then I created a collection called coll3

```
use mydb
db.coll3.insert({"1":"HI"})
```

When I do this

```
db.coll3.find()
```

I get this error

> Couldn't retrieve documents
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException cannot be cast to t3.utils.document.g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the query object (an empty object to return all documents) to the find function:

```
db.coll3.find({})
```

[Refer to the MongoDB documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: Same problem still

Comment: Any other suggestion

Comment: I figured out the error it required a restart ,THANX ANYWAYS

Comment: Restart of what??

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 db.getCollection('coll3').find({})
```

Comment: I figured out the error it required a restart ,THANX ANYWAYS